# How to add sorting for related table's columns by default

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using Backpack 3.5 for laravel 5.7, I have two tables related by 1-n. I need to show rows from first table sorted by column in related table, how can this be done?

For sorting in the first table there is a method 
`$this->crud->orderBy('column', 'order');` but it doesn't work for other related columns

Comment: need more code, what is `$this->crud` returning a query builder or a collection ?

Comment: well $this->crud is Backpack's object, a CrudPanel. It contains implementation for crud operations

Comment: how are u loading the related table ?

Comment: To show columns from related table, I use method $this->crud->addColumn from backpack API, set the type of column 'select', which means data from connected entity should be loaded. I think Backpack loads related table by relation in Eloquent Model